# convert pixel values to image in c++

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a file which has 2 columns. 1st column has all pixel positions and second has value corresponding to that pixel. This pixel value is very small (of order E-9).

I want to create an image of size 512x512 with pixel positions given in text file colored with same color. So, pixel value does not matter.

Please, tell me how to do this in c++ and what additional libraries are required.

Input file

872      4.19078e-010
1000     4.59096e-009
1127     1.2677e-010
1128     8.78192e-010
1255     1.59879e-009
7233     9.87113e-010
7234     2.1458e-009
8130     8.00793e-007
8131     9.02571e-007
8258     8.23907e-007
8259     6.44226e-007
8264     1.68967e-009
8265     1.9245e-009
8385     7.74323e-010
8386     2.10707e-009
8387     2.77237e-009
8388     2.12874e-009
8513     2.81146e-010
8516     1.08573e-008

Comment: Show us a few lines of your input file please. And also explain why you are telling us that the pixel values are small (E-9) and then in the next sentence that the value doesn't matter as you want them all the same colour anyway - doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't know which format stores values of this order and if pixels are colored with same color then also its fine. I have added few lines of input file

Comment: Ok, so looking at your first and last pixels listed. Where does pixel position 872 belong in the 512x512 image? And where does pixel 8516 belong in the 512x512 image?

Comment: starting from 0 index. 872 belongs to (1,360) and 8516 belongs to (16,324)

Comment: Ok, and are we assuming it is a greyscale image or colour? And what pixel value goes at positions 872 and 8516?

Comment: Consider it a grayscale image with value 255.

Comment: Ok, I have got it now. Are you on Windows or Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you look at the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net) package, and specifically the PGM format - Portable Greymap [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html). It is very easy to write in C without a library as it is pure ASCII which is fine for small files and easy to deal with. Basically, your file would look like this in PGM format:

```
P2
512 512
255
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .... 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 .... 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 .... 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The `P2` just says it's greyscale and ASCII. The `512 512` are the dimensions and the `255` is the max pixel brightness. You then have 512 scanlines of your image, each one has 512 pixel values separated by spaces. Black pixels are zero. White pixels are 255. So the 255 in the above example is your pixel number 872 near the end of the second scanline.

Once you have a PGM/PBM file you can easily convert it to anything else with ImageMagick or even read it directly into many applications - e.g. Photoshop.

There is an example [here](http://ugurkoltuk.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/an-extreme-simple-pgm-io-api/), look at line 51 onwards for an example of the P5 format which is similar to the P2 format but in binary instead of ASCII.

Here is what I get for your inputs:
[image]

**ADDED LATER**

Just for fun, I have converted your data using `awk` without needing any C programming at all. It is a one-liner like this (spread over 3 lines for readability):

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "P5\n512 512\n255\n";for(i=0;i<512*512;i++)p[i]=0}
     {p[$1]=255}
     END {for(i=0;i<512*512;i++)printf "%c",p[i]}' yourfile > image.pgm
```

That says, at the beginning of the script (i.e. `BEGIN{}`), output `P5\n512 512\n255` for the header, and zero all elements of my pixel array `p[]`. Then, on all subsequent lines, set to 255 the pixel indexed by the first value ($1) on each line of your input file. Then, at the end (`END{}`) print all elements of the pixel array `p[]` and send the whole lot to a file called `image.pgm`.

If you fancy using this, you will need to download awk for Windows - probably from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net)

**EDITED**

If you want to use the original values for each pixel rather than simply using pure white (255) for every pixel in your input file, we need to do some more work. Firstly, as we read each pixel, we must save its value (it's in `$2`) as well as its position. Then, at the end, we will have to scale the values onto some range, so I have arbitrarily chosen that the the smallest value in your file will result in mid-grey (i.e. value=127 in output image) and that the largest value in your file will result in full white (i.e. value=255 in output image). All other pixels in your input file will fall in their corresponding (linear) position between mid-grey(127) and white (255). Any pixels not in your input file will be black.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "P5\n512 512\n255\n";for(i=0;i<512*512;i++)p[i]=0}

     {p[$1]=$2}

     END {
        # Find min and max readings so we can scale them into range [128,255]
        max=0;min=1000000
        for(i=0;i<512*512;i++){
           if(p[i]!=0){
              if(p[i]>max)max=p[i]
              if(p[i]<min)min=p[i]
           }
        }
        # Calculate range of readings
        range=max-min
        scalefactor=128/range
        # Scale all readings
        for(i=0;i<512*512;i++){
           if(p[i]!=0){
              p[i]=127+int((p[i]-min)*scalefactor)
           }
        }
        # Print the values to the pgm file
        for(i=0;i<512*512;i++)printf "%c",p[i]
     }' yourfile > image.pgm
```

The histogram I get with this code is as follows:

```
    14: (127,127,127) #7F7F7F gray(127)
     1: (128,128,128) #808080 gray(128)
     1: (218,218,218) #DADADA gray(218)
     1: (240,240,240) #F0F0F0 gray(240)
     1: (243,243,243) #F3F3F3 gray(243)
     1: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)
```

So it results in 14 pixels of mid-gray (127), 1 pixel of 128, one pixel of 218, one of 218, one of 240, one of 243 and one of 255 (white).

Comment: I have updated this answer - with a mini awk program that does what I think you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store original pixel values instead of same value to every pixel.

Comment: I have updated the code for you at the end of my answer. Click my profile and Email me directly if you need any more help.